# Получить имя пользователя компьютера

Tags: javascript, php

Возможно ли средствами `PHP` а может вдруг `JS` получить имя пользователя компьютера? Не имя компьютера, а и именно имя пользователя который активен в данный момент.
компьютеры находятся в доменной сети. смотрел в сторону LDAP но сервер не хранит информации связку IP и имя пользователя

Comment: `$username = getenv('USERNAME');`. `var wshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var wshEnv = wshShell.Environment("PROCESS");
var Username = wshEnv("USERNAME");`.

Comment: *сервер не хранит информации связку IP и имя пользователя* Ясен пень... одному IP могут соответствовать несколько имён - вторичные входы в систему и runas - они такие...

Comment: средствами `js` нельзя